# nuxt3: authMiddleware with pinia store have some issue when reload page

Tags: authentication, state-management, nuxt3, pinia

i have authStore to store my login state, i use useLocalStorage of @vueuse.
in some page require user login like cart. i use middleware of nuxt3. It work but when i reload, my website redirect to login page althougth i am logged

in stores/auth.js

```
export const authStore = defineStore("auth", () => {
  let authUser = useLocalStorage("pinia/auth/login", {});
  // let isLogged = useLocalStorage(false)
  let token = useLocalStorage("dung_dong_vao_cai_nay","")
  let timeExpried = useLocalStorage(0)
  let errorMessage = ref("");
  const userq = computed(() => authUser.value);
....others code
```

in middleware/auth.js

```
import { authStore } from "../stores/auth"
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) => {
    const auth = authStore()
    if (!auth.userq.username) {
        return navigateTo('/auth/login')
    }
    navigateTo(to.fullPath)  
  }
  )
```

in cart/index.vue

```
definePageMeta({
middleware: [
  function (to, from) {
    // Custom inline middleware
  },
  'auth',
],
});
```